# grid column issue on Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, grid-layout

I have this content page in xaml

```
<ContentPage.Content>            
    <StackLayout x:Name="stackMadre" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  >
        <Picker x:Name="picTipoServizio" 
                SelectedIndexChanged="picTipoServizio_SelectedIndexChanged" >  
                <Picker.Items>
                    <x:String>Item1</x:String>
                    <x:String>Item2</x:String>
                    <x:String>Item3</x:String>
                </Picker.Items>                   
        </Picker>
    
        <ScrollView x:Name="scrollView" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"> 
        <tabView:SfTabView x:Name="tabView" TabItemTapped="TabView_TabItemTapped" SelectionChanged="SfTabView_SelectionChanged"
                           VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"   >           
       </tabView:SfTabView>
          </ScrollView>           
    </StackLayout>       
</ContentPage.Content>
```

when the page is initialized, I create a grid that populates the content of the currently selected tabitem with this code

```
Grid grid = new Grid();
        //cera la griglia 
        grid.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(0.7 , GridUnitType.Star)  });
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(0.3, GridUnitType.Star) });
```

and after this it always works on the basis of other controls I go to create the necessary row with this code

```
grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = 100 });
                       grid.Children.Add(label, 0, p);
                       grid.Children.Add(button, 1, p);
```

for the first tab it's ok but for the second tab I have this problem,
the grid is not formed correctly. look the screen

firstTab ==>: https://i.stack.imgur.com/io4w8.jpg

secondTab ==>: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPZYx.jpg

in the same code I have another problem that is that the scroll of the scrollview does not work, do you have any idea?

Comment: how are you adding the grids to the tabs?

Comment: assigning a function to the content of the selected tab that returns the gird

Comment: please post the actual code

Comment: The problem must be in some code that you haven't shown. *"content of the currently selected tabitem"* - the code snippet you post doesn't mention a tabitem. Nor do you show the creation of the tabitems. Perhaps the second tab isn't filling the width. Perhaps you now have a grid with 4 columns, instead of 2 grids, one per tab, each with 2 columns. The best way to debug what is wrong, is to start with simpler code. If you put a background color on the second tab, does that color fill the width?

Comment: Seems like 2nd tab isn't defaulting to `HorizontallOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand`.  MAYBE it gets laid out when the page first appears. Even though it is not visible yet. But it has no contents, so doesn't get full width.

Comment: in the same code I have another problem that is that the scroll of the scrollview does not work, do you have any idea?

Comment: Could you provide the code snipptes for us to reproduce? We need more details.